# difference between servlet lifecycle and filter lifecycle

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

is there any difference between servlet and filter lifecycle?.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, both a servlet and a filter:

- are instantiated (once) when the context starts
- the `init(..)` method is called
- they handle each request - first it passes through all filters and then reaches the servlet
- when the context is destroyed (i.e. when your container stops, or your application is undeployed from the manager console), the `destroy(..)` method is called

Comment: your answer is great but I think there is a bit of difference about when they are instantiated. Pls check my answer :D. Anyway +1 for your answer :D

Answer (score 10):

So far I was also wondering the differences. I created a web project to observe life-cycle of them. It can be check-outed at

```
http://dntuan-java-workspace.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/simple-web
```

Once it is deployed on tomcat, you can observe logs from the console to see that filters are initialized **before context is started**. Whereas servlet is only initialized when **a request is made** (e.g. `http://localhost:8080/simple-web/servlet/life.jsp`)

---

**More information** from [JSR-000315 JavaTM Servlet 3.0](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr315/):

> ### 2.3.1 Loading and Instantiation
>
> The servlet container is responsible for loading and instantiating
>   servlets. The  loading and instantiation can occur when the container
>   is started, or delayed until  the container determines the servlet is
>   needed to service a request.
>
> ### 6.2.1 Filter Lifecycle
>
> After deployment of the Web application, and before a request causes
>   the container  to access a Web resource, the container must locate the
>   list of filters that must be  applied to the Web resource as described
>   below. The container must ensure that it  has instantiated a filter of
>   the appropriate class for each filter in the list, and called  its
>   init(FilterConfig config)method.