# Lifecycle of a servlet filter

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

I am new to servlets.
So far i know about the servlet lifecycle,
ie

1. Servlet class loading and creating object for that Servlet.
2. Creating  "ServletConfig" object and calls init() method by passing that object.
3. Creating  "request" and "response" objects and  call doGet()/dopost() method by passing those objects.
4. Finally calling destroy() method.

But,
        I dont know the filter lifecycle?
        May I Know the filter life cycle?
        And What is the difference between "Servlet LifeCycle" and "Filter LifeCycle"?

Comment: read the exact same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786111/difference-between-servlet-lifecycle-and-filter-lifecycle

Comment: please check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/22919940/1521627 and @bozho 's one

Answer (score -2):

Basically in Filter's you need to map the filter's with your servlet using url patterns where one needs to mention in the servlet, as to what request needs to be passed to be passed from one servlet to the another.

For example if servlet 1 needs to pass some information to another servlet. One needs to map the filter with that servlet specifically in the xml file as to where the servlet needs to be passed, using filters as a medium as such.